# Using sessions in simple add function

Tags: php, mysql, session, shopping-cart

I am currently following a PHP tutorial from PHP academy on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&NR=1&v=QOKNQDClDg4) and we are creating a shopping cart. So far we are using sessions to account for the products added. When I try to echo the session it produces a `Notice: Undefined index: cart_1 in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\Formula One\script\cart.php on line 28` error. Why is this so? In the tutorial video it adds a 1 to the next page and when clicked on again it goes to 2. Looking on their forum there are some suggestions to use `ISSET` before. Thanks alot.

```
 <?php
session_start();

include("../script/dbconnect.php");

$page1 = 'index.php'; //page reference

if (isset($_GET['add'])) { // cart add button
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
}

function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) ==0) {
    echo"There are no products to display!";
    }
else {
  while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
        echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br />'.$get_row['description'].'<br />'.$get_row['price'].' <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add Here</a></p>';
        }
    }
}

echo $_SESSION['cart_1'];

?>
```

Comment: The notice is telling you that the $_SESSION['cart_1'] is not defined. You may check it before using or you can just disable this message in your php.ini, as this is not a serious error

Comment: If any tutorial makes reference to `mysql_query`, **throw it away**. This interface is from the 1990s and is deprecated, destined to be removed, and will produce warnings in PHP 5.5 or later. New applications should be using [PDO](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe SQL injection bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a check before use a var potentially undefined

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']])) 
       $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] = 0;

$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
```

and

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart_1']))
    echo $_SESSION['cart_1'];
else
    echo "session cart_1 not defined";
```

in linked video there is no displayed error because the [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) ini php.ini of author is probably set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

EDIT: I see now the video. Please try to find another tutorial where:

- error_reporting is set to `E_ALL`
- use [pdo_*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) function instead of mysql_*